# Get data from rviz

Tags: rviz, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, so today I did my first simple work on rviz - projecting depth image data onto the plane using the pointcould display. I am wondering whether theres is way to get the final graph display data from rviz and probably later reproduce the same plot in say MATLAB. I know I can get the depth/image/points message by simply echoing out the topic.
If so, how easiest can I achieve this? Thank you all very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303667/get-data-from-rviz/) by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**RVIZ** is just visual tool for displaying **ROS** messages, therefore getting data from **RVIZ** means getting data from **ROS** topic. **MATLAB** has support for **ROS** (look [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html)). You should be able to create subscriber (look [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/robotics.subscriber.html)) in **MATLAB** to the given topic and do whatever you want with the data.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2018-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2018-09-22**:
Thanks. I will take a look into how to create the same visual images then.

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2018-11-08**:
worked like a charm :)

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-11-08**:
glad to help